# javascript Escape function if called from within same function

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Hello I have a function that I only need to run if called outside of the function.  When I hit `this.grid.onSelectedRowsChanged.subscribe(this.proxy("clickCheckBox"));` ...it goes back into the function

Is there something I can set inside the function so that if it is called again from within a second time?

This is sample code

```
    this.grid.onSelectedRowsChanged.subscribe(this.proxy("clickCheckBox")); //Listener....

"clickCheckBox" : function(e, args)  {
                    this.dataview.beginUpdate();
                    this.grid.setSelectedRows(someRows);  //This calls this function again
                    this.dataview.endUpdate();
                    this.grid.render();

                },
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with slickgrid, but is there any way you can pass data to the event object or to `args` for the SelectedRowsChanged event? Alternatively, can you unsubscribe the proxy, set the selected rows, and then re-subscribe it?